# gcc: undefined reference to _mcount (gprof instrumentation)

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, profiling, solaris, gprof

When compiling my c++ sources with the `-pg` option to inject gprof profile instrumentation code the compile fails with the `undefined reference to _mcount` error.

Without this option everything compiles (and runs) fine.
What is wrong in my case? (Solaris 10 SPARC Platform)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you **both** compiling each object file and linking the final executable using the '-pg' flag?

Comment: How can I make sure I'm  linking the final executable using the '-pg' flag?

Comment: @AtheelMassalha That depends what build system you are using.  You should start a new question.