# "Undefined reference to `mcount'" when trying to use -pg [Termux]

Tags: android, c++, g++, profiling, gprof

I've completed the first part of my project, and I want to know how well / bad it performs by profiling it with `gprof`. I am working on Android using a Linux emulator named Termux, and I am using g++ as the compiler.

Everything compiles without errors and even warnings, and the binary runs perfectly.

So I decided to put the `-pg` flag among the other flags in my makefile, (meaning that both compilation and linking is performed with `-pg`) and tried recompiling everything. But something seems to not work properly: during compilation, everything is normal. But when linking I get a `argument unused during compilation: '-pg'` warning and then a lot of `undefined reference to 'mcount'` (it doesn't even display all of them, after a bit it says `more undefined references to 'mcount' follows`) errors, and at the end a `linker command failed with exit code 1` error.

What is causing this behaviour? Is something broken / missing on the platform I am using? Can I fix that? How?

Comment: you have to link with `-pg` too: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Compiling.html

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I am already doing it. Also everythong is fine during linking, the issue happens when I'm combining all of them to form the binary.

Comment: If I were mean I would tag it as duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603298/gcc-undefined-reference-to-mcount-gprof-instrumentation

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre even if I said and repeated that I'm compiling everything with `-pg`?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the short answer, but I'm on mobile.  Making a community wiki.

In Termux, `g++` is a symlink to `clang`.  `-pg` is a gnu feature, so does not function when linking using clang.

You could use clang-appropriate techniques for profiling, or install a real `g++`.  One reference is https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182130/use-gcc-compiler-in-termux but there is also "google performance tools" for profiling out there somewhere.